# Point Free Style Required for Optimized Curry

Tags: haskell, ghc, currying, pointfree, partial-application

Say we have a (contrived) function like so:

```
import Data.List (sort)

contrived :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
contrived a b = (sort a) ++ b
```

And we partially apply it to use elsewhere, eg:

```
map (contrived [3,2,1]) [[4],[5],[6]]
```

On the surface, this works as one would expect:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6]]
```

However, if we throw some `trace`s in:

```
import Debug.Trace (trace)

contrived :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
contrived a b = (trace "sorted" $ sort a) ++ b
map (contrived $ trace "a value" [3,2,1]) [[4],[5],[6]]
```

We see that the first list passed into `contrived` is evaluated only once, but it is sorted for each item in `[4,5,6]`:

```
[sorted
a value
[1,2,3,4],sorted
[1,2,3,5],sorted
[1,2,3,6]]
```

Now, `contrived` can be rather simply translated to point-free style:

```
contrived :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
contrived a = (++) (sort a)
```

Which when partially applied:

```
map (contrived [3,2,1]) [4,5,6]
```

Still works as we expect:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6]]
```

But if we again add `trace`s:

```
contrived :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
contrived a = (++) (trace "sorted" $ sort a)
map (contrived $ trace "a value" [3,2,1]) [[4],[5],[6]]
```

We see that now the first list passed into `contrived` is evaluated **and sorted** only once:

```
[sorted
a value
[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,3,6]]
```

Why is this so? Since the translation into pointfree style is so trivial, why can't GHC deduce that it only needs to sort `a` once in the first version of `contrived`?

---

**Note:** I know that for this rather trivial example, it's probably preferable to use pointfree style. This is a contrived example that I've simplified quite a bit. The real function that I'm having the issue with is less clear (in my opinion) when expressed in pointfree style:

```
realFunction a b = conditionOne && conditionTwo
  where conditionOne = map (something a) b
        conditionTwo = somethingElse a b
```

In pointfree style, this requires writing an ugly wrapper (`both`) around `(&&)`:

```
realFunction a = both conditionOne conditionTwo
  where conditionOne = map (something a)
        conditionTwo = somethingElse a
        both f g x = (f x) && (g x)
```

As an aside, I'm also not sure why the `both` wrapper works; the pointfree style of `realFunction` behaves like the pointfree style version of `contrived` in that the partial application is only evaluated once (ie. if `something` sorted `a` it would only do so once). It appears that since `both` is not pointfree, Haskell should have the same issue that it had with the non-pointfree `contrived`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for this:

```
contrived :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
contrived a = let a' = sort a in \b -> a' ++ b
                    -- or ... in (a' ++)
```

If you want the sort to be computed only once, it has to be done before the `\b`.

You are correct in that a compiler could optimize this. This is known as the "full laziness" optimization.

If I remember correctly, GHC does not always do it because it's not always an actual optimization, in the general case. Consider the contrived example

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo x y = let a = [1..x] in length a + y
```

When passing both arguments, the above code works in constant space: the list elements are immediately garbage collected as they are produced.

When partially applying `x`, the closure for `foo x` only requires O(1) memory, since the list is not yet generated. Code like

```
let f = foo 1000 in f 10 + f 20  -- (*)
```

still run in constant space.

Instead, if we wrote

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo x = let a = [1..x] in (length a +)
```

then `(*)` would no longer run in constant space. The first call `f 10` would allocate a 1000-long list, and keep it in memory for the second call `f 20`.

---

Note that your partial application

```
... = (++) (sort a)
```

essentially means

```
... = let a' = sort a in \b -> a' ++ b
```

since argument passing involves a binding, as in `let`. So, the result of your `sort a` is kept around for all the future calls.

Comment: +1 (+ more if I could!) Thanks for a really clear explanation. I see why GHC doesn't make this optimization by default given the general case. I forgot to mention that I tried using `($!)` to force strict evaluation of the sort. I must've been doing it wrong, because lo and behold `($!)` is just another spelling of the let construct you suggested!

Comment: @BaileyParker Actually, `let` does not force evaluation immediately, while `$!` does force the argument. `let x = e in f x + g x` will evaluate `e` only when it is needed by `f,g`, but will save its value in memory for the second call.